# How to transform one icon to another

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, html5-canvas

Is it possible to convert one shape to another for example two SVG icons. One is a bird (twitter) and one is F (facebook). So I want to make an animation to convert the shape of the bird into the F. example: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=2f3905c

I am not sure how to do it, of it is efficient at all. People have created similar styles like converting menu button to a close button. But I am not sure what technology would help to create it.

So please let me know how I can do it. And any possible an example.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you need help, the first step you can take is posting the relevant code you already have here. So please do.

Comment: [This Greensock plugin](http://greensock.com/morphsvg-update?utm_source=Newsletter-December&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=morphSVG-update) morphs svg-to-svg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of JavaScript libraries that can help with this - the term you should be searching for is *SVG morphing*.

Here's an example using [SVG Morpheus](https://github.com/alexk111/SVG-Morpheus):

```js
var iconElement = document.getElementById('icon');
var icon = new SVGMorpheus(iconElement, { rotation: 'none' });


iconElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Morph to the icon with the given ID
  icon.to('square');
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/SVG-Morpheus/0.1.8/svg-morpheus.js"></script>

<svg id="icon">
  <!-- Place each icon in a group (<g> tag) with a unique ID -->
  <g id="square">
    <rect width="100" height ="100" />
  </g>
  <g id="circle">
    <ellipse rx="50" ry="50" cx="50" cy="50" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -2):

An alternative, possible not desirably for quality purposes, is to make a gif with the animations in it.